# NestJS - Status Code set to 204 but API Response status code is still 200

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I created an API that requires returning 204 - No Content Response

```
import { Controller, Get, Header, HttpStatus, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';


@Get("mediation-get-api")
    @Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
    @Header("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN always")
    async getMediationAPI(@Req() _request,
        @Res() _res) {
        let APIResponse: any
        APIResponse = await this.ServiceObj.getResult(_request)
        console.log("APIResponse point")
        console.log(APIResponse)
        
        if (APIResponse != undefined) {
            console.log("Not Empty Response")
            _res.json(APIResponse.data).status(HttpStatus.OK)
            _res.statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
            _res.statusMessage = APIResponse.statusText
        } else {
            console.log("Empty Response")
            _res.json({}).status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
            _res.statusCode = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
            // _res.statusMessage = "No Content"
        }

        console.log("Response")
        console.log(_res)
        return _res
    }
```

Here even after setting HttpStatus, API response seems to still be 200 OK

I tried setting status code in Headers but still no change

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `res.json()` invoke the `write()` and `end()` methods of the response, meaning what happens after it are disregarded? That's why it's usually `res.status().json()`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, Thanks a lot
I tried adding status(204) before .json() and it seems to work as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.status()` needs to be called before `.json()` as `.json()` will end up calling `.send()` which will end the response, and any later modifications will not take effect